# Why does SQL Management Studio add a cross join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, ssms, cross-join

I sometimes need to run basic updates on a join. For example:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = 'val1'
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.ID = t2.t1_id
WHERE t2.col3 = 'val3'
```

This works perfectly, but for some reason, in MS SQL Management Studio Express, it wants to convert this to

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = 'val1'
FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.ID = t2.t1_id
CROSS JOIN t2
WHERE t2.col3 = 'val3'
```

It adds a crossjoin for some reason that I don't understand.

Now my question is: Why does Management Studio think this is what I meant? It must have a genuine use, otherwise it wouldn't suggest it. Yet I have no idea how and when (and why).

Comment: in the SQL pane, yes, right after I hit execute. I know it sounds weird. If you want I can get you two screenshots before and after I hit execute.

Comment: oh, it also happens when instead of clicking execute, you click 'Verify SQL Syntax' in the SQL pane

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying, because as far as I know, the standard query execution window (right click on the database > New Query) will NEVER perform any kind of rewrite on your query. Could you elaborate as to how exactly you elicit this behaviour?

Comment: No, that one doesn't. But the query pane that you can open when browsing a table does.

Comment: Other changes it makes are for example expanding * to all column names, and reorganising conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx) a cross join like that is equivalent to an inner join.  Perhaps it uses cross joins because a cross join can be used to create cartesian products as well as simpler joins - whereas an inner join is more limited.

Answer (score 2):

It must be a bug, because your fist code is rigth.

Try

Update t1 set col1 = 'val1'
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.id = t2.t1_id and t2.col3='val3'

It throws the same result, but it could be less efficient. 
Does your SQL-MS add any code?
Strange...

Comment: Only in the SQL pane that opens op when you browse a table. This is a common error for me when I use the 'wrong tab' in Management studio.

Comment: I have the same behavior.  If I run this type of update query in the "Edit Top 200 Rows" pane it wants to add the cross join into the query.  If I run the same update statement in a query window then it works just fine.